# Connection refused al conectarse con Metabase a una base de datos MySQL

Tags: mysql

Intento connectarme a una database local MySQL que se llama `time_series` con metabase pero al connectarme obtengo el siguiente error.

```
Database name: Could not connect to address=(host=127.0.0.1)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:127.0.0.1, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

El usuario no tiene password.

Sin embargo que es un problema conocido hasta que parece que [el conector MariaDB, utilizado por Metabase, no es actualmente compatible con MySQL 8](https://www.metabase.com/docs/v0.43/administration-guide/databases/mysql.html#connecting-to-mysql-8-servers).

Entonces intenté el commando que proponen:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
```

pero me contesta el compliador:

```
Error Code: 1396. Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'%'
```

Intenté modificar el usuario y crearlo nuevamente como lo propone rpaillo pero tengo un error sin muchas explicaciones:

```
DROP USER `root`;
CREATE USER `root` IDENTIFIED BY "root";
```

Obtengo:

```
Error Code: 1396. Operation DROP USER failed for 'root'@'%'
```

Comment: Chequea que el usuario está bien definido con : ``SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;``

Comment: Si, me devuelve `root localhost` @rpaillao

Comment: Entonces es ese usuario al que tienes que setear el password, no a 'root'@'%'

Comment: Okay @rpaillao , entonces hicé `ALTER USER 'root' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';` pero me contesta el mismo error: `Error Code: 1396. Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'%'`. De todo modo, gracias para la ayuda

Comment: Si el error es a nivel de socket, los primeros sospechosos son los cortafuegos.

Comment: hay que eliminar el usuario y crearlo nuevamente, revisa este [link](https://sebhastian.com/mysql-error-1396/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el commentario @rpaillao Lo intenté pero me deveuelve un error. He anadido los logs pero no hay muchas explicaciones